# Sorting 'new look' Google Spreadsheet with multiple parameters using script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that we use to track jobs in our production shop, and sort them based on a few criteria such as due date, proof date, order date and so on. We've used a google doc for almost 2 years now for this, so everyone can see from their desk where their job sits in triage. That whole time, the following code sat in an onEdit() trigger:

```
function sortSheet() {
  var range = "A2:R250";
  var sortList = WIPpage.getRange(range);
  sortList.sort([{column: 8, ascending: false}, 6, 5, 10, 7, 2]);
}
```

Day before yesterday, we got the "check out your sheet under the new look of google" message, and then sort stopped working. I now get the error:

```
Sort range must include all columns on a form sheet.
```

referring to the sortList.sort line.

Anyone have any clue how to sort a google sheet by different parameters under the new and improved system?

Comment: This may help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)   the parameter in the sort method is an array.

Comment: I apologize, the original code was actually in that format with square brackets, and the error code was 'Sort range must include all columns on a form sheet.' I will change question.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the issue is that the page in question is the target of a form submission, which the new system doesn't like.

I have since changed the form target to a new page in the same sheet and I added the following function with the onEdit and on form response trigger:

```
function FormResponse() {
var newRow = FRMpage.getLastRow();
var newEntry = FRMpage.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
if (newEntry[0][10] != true) {
  WIPpage.appendRow([newEntry[0][0], newEntry[0][1],newEntry[0][2],newEntry[0][3],newEntry[0][4],newEntry[0][5],newEntry[0][6],newEntry[0][7],newEntry[0][8],newEntry[0][9]]);
  FRMpage.getRange(newRow, 11).setValue(true);
  sortSheet();
  }
}
```

where sortSheet() is the original function in the question.

If there's a way to make the old system work and not have to add another sheet and run this function constantly, I'd still appreciate it, but this seems to be working for now.

This isn't the prettiest answer in the world, but hopefully it will help someone else having the same problem.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I manually added the "True" column to the response sheet. That's not on the form, as I don't want the people filling it out to see it.